# Only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices - dont understand code

Tags: python

Apologies for the easy question, but i really dont understand what the below code is trying to do? I keep getting the error saying it's not a valid index, but its hard to resolve that when i don't understand the code itself. I am trying to update it, i found it on github

```
PatternNumber = np.repeat(np.nan, data.shape[0])
PNID = np.argwhere((~np.isnan(NB_Cat)) & (~np.isnan(AM_Cat)) & (~np.isnan(AF_Cat)) & (~np.isnan(NR_Cat))).T[0]
PatternNumber[PNID] = NB_Cat[PNID]*36+AM_Cat[PNID]*12+AF_Cat[PNID]*3+NR_Cat[PNID]*1+1
#print(PNID)
print(Wrk_Beta_all)
i=int(0)
for i in PNID:
  i+=1
  print(i)
  Beta = Wrk_Beta_all[data.Race[i-1]]
```

For extra context, PNID is an array

[    0     1     2 ... 78206 78207 78208]

and Wrk_Beta_all is

```
[[ 0.52926417  0.09401031  0.21862622  0.95830278 -0.28804248 -0.19081139]
 [ 0.18221211  0.26725303  0.          0.47572426 -0.11194117  0.        ]
 [ 0.09707836  0.          0.23183683  0.16668544  0.          0.        ]
 [ 0.52926417  0.09401031  0.21862622  0.95830278 -0.28804248 -0.19081139]
 [ 0.4798624   0.25939223  0.46692462  0.90766797  0.          0.        ]
 [ 0.55263612  0.07499258  0.27638268  0.79185634  0.          0.        ]
 [ 0.55263612  0.07499258  0.27638268  0.79185634  0.          0.        ]
 [ 0.55263612  0.07499258  0.27638268  0.79185634  0.          0.        ]
 [ 0.55263612  0.07499258  0.27638268  0.79185634  0.          0.        ]
 [ 0.55263612  0.07499258  0.27638268  0.79185634  0.          0.        ]
 [ 0.55263612  0.07499258  0.27638268  0.79185634  0.          0.        ]]
```

And data is my df, Race is a column in that df

The specific line giving an error is Beta = Wrk_Beta_all[data.Race[i-1]] and I'm trying to understand what it is actually trying to do

Comment: What is the value of `data.Race[i-1]`?

Comment: data.Race[i-1] is returning what kind of value? Is it a string? It should return the value of the ith-1 row in data.Race, which in turn would be trying to access that nth element in Wrk_Beta_all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason [data.Race[i-1]] was cast as a float so i cast it as an int just before and it worked